# How to run thousands of queries in Ms Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've discovered the SQL VIEW in Ms Access to execute some queries, but I need to execute about 20.000 UPDATE queries I have in a .sql file.

When I paste in the SQL VIEW it says the "Text is too long to modify".

How can I run those UPDATE's ?

Comment: You have one file with 20,000 queries or 20,000 files with one query in each? I'm afraid to ask why.

Comment: One file with 20.000 queries ... one per line ending in ";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit to the number of characters in an Access SQL query is "about 64000" - see here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx. And unfortunately you cannot execute multiple statements in a query. I think this will mean quite a bit of work for you in VBA. Here is an example approach (pseudocode):-

```
open file
read line into variable
while not EOF
currentdb.execute variable, dbfailonerror
read next line
wend
close file
```

Probably a nasty surprise for you if you are used to executing huge batches of statements using other RDBMS!

An alternative suggestion: we don't know exactly what your file looks like or where it comes from, but if it is generated from another RDBMS which you have access to, then I would very strongly recommend that you set up an ODBC connection to it, and query out the data you need (either by linking the tables or writing a pass through query), then inserting into your local Access tables. This will be many orders of magnitude faster than executing thousands of individual statements.

If your only source of the data is the SQL statements then you may still be better of if you can parse the SQL text into relevant columns (for example PK, and value to be updated, or if inserting, then all column values), then save as a csv file, import into Access, add keys as necessary, and then run a single update statement as an updateable query against the imported data and the existing tables. Dumping the file into Excel and using the various string functions may enable you to parse the data quite quickly.

Comment: Don't _call_ `CurrentDB` 20,000 times.  CurrentDb is **not** a static object, rather a method call which reopens a new database object each time.  Instead do something like `Set db = CurrentDB` before the loop, then call `db.Execute`  I realize this is only pseudo code, but just one example of why a simple quick "give me the code" answer doesn't work well for this kind of question.

Comment: @CPerkins you are quite correct in your comments about CurrentDB and it should never be used like this in practice.I also don't think I would ever try to execute 20000 statements in a loop!

Comment: @FlamingMoe. I think you would benefit from adding some debug information to your VBA code so that we can see where it is failing. Before DoCmd.RunSQL (or db.execute) insert a debug.print StrIn to check the SQL statement. You can then execute in the immediate window db.execute "blah blah", dbfailonerror and see what the error condition is. I'll edit my answer with another suggestion that may be better.

Answer (score -1):

There may be an easier way but you could write VBA code that reads the text file line by line and then uses `DoCmd.RunSQL` to run each query.

Comment: Can you give me more details, please ? ;-)  I'm MySQL DBA,  nothing to do with MS Acces, but I have this issue right now :-P

Comment: This: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/714d453c-d97a-4567-bd5f-64651e29c93a/how-to-read-text-a-file-into-a-string-1line-at-a-time-search-it-for-keyword-data?forum=accessdev should get you started. Ignore the part about searching the string for keywords.

Comment: No, you are still missing a lot of the critical elements from the solutions in the link. You can't take shortcuts; you have to obtain at least a basic understanding of what each command does in the examples so that you can modify it for your needs.

Comment: And I can not pretend to learn VBA in 5 minutes ... you could help more instead just pointing to a "non similar" example :-)

Comment: Also, I imagine that `DoCmd.RunSQL` is very inefficient for running thousands of queries, one after another, since it is essentially an Access macro command.  I suggesting instead using ADO (or DAO) to have the ACE (Jet) database engine execute the queries directly.  This will bypass unnecessary Access overhead.

Comment: @FlamingMoe - Not in a position to write and test code.

Comment: @C Perkins - I am trying to keep it as simple as possible. If you can provide example code by all means post an answer.

Comment: @SunKnight0  If you think it's appropriate to simply hand over bulk, working code at the PO's demand, be my guest.  Sorry for injecting my opinion between you two.  But since I've been using SO, I see over and over replies that this is not a code writing service... from scratch at least, especially for someone who doesn't yet know the particular language about which they're asking.

Comment: @C Perkins - I agree when it comes to bulk code but this is <10 lines and it seems more like a one time thing the OP has to deal with rather than classwork or homework someone is trying to get away without doing,

Comment: @SunKnight0 10 lines is a naive estimate, since it'll need to correctly parse each statement, I assume multi-line, delimited by semicolons, with error handling. I would normally suggest wrapping multiple updates in a transactions, but I have no idea if ACE/Jet engine can handle that many updates for each transactions, etc. A proper solution should essentially require whoever's doing it to learn details of VBA and Access databases... PO also didn't mention if these are all pass-through queries to linked tables, perhaps in a MySQL database. That just adds more details to consider, etc., etc.

Comment: @C Perkins -  An .sql file with 20000 UPDATE statements sounds more like something exported from another DBMS, so I would expect relative simplicity and line breaks after each one so actual working code would not be much bigger than pseudo code in the accepted answer above. If things were indeed more complicated than that, of course the OP would have to take the base code and improve on it. Anyway, I generally don't write original code here, but if I already have code I can copy/paste I usually don't mind sharing.

Comment: No, it's a very old database running in Access 2003 since a lot of years ago, where I need to UPDATE just the prices, and I did the UPDATE commands with an external tool/editor, and now I have the 20000 update commands and I do not know how to run them in the Access. That's the reason.

Comment: Then you are totally going the wrong way about it. You should crate an excel or csv file with item ID and price, import it into access as a table and do a single UPDATE query to update all the prices.